# Reassigning the value of variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a program to use the Babylonian Method for square roots, and this requires reassigning the values of variables

```
radicand=gets.to_f
A=rand(1..radicand)
B = A+1
while B != A
  C = radicand/A
  B = A
  A = (A+C)/2
end
print"The square root of #{radicand} is #{A}"
```

When I run this, I'll get an answer among an insane number of error messages. The answer is always correct, so why does this code cause so many problems?

[Console with error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8IYY.png)

[image]

Comment: Your question is all about the error messages you are getting but you haven't told us what they are or on what lines they occur. Please edit to provide that information.

Comment: You didn’t include the error messages, but did you read them? “warning: already initialized constant A”. Why does it think `A` is a constant? Look up “ruby constant”: https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html Ah, it starts with an uppercase letter. Well, use the standard lowercase for variable names.

Comment: Those error messages pinpoint the problem. They are warnings that you are changing the values of constants. Ruby lets you do that but it is not good practice. Change all your constants (upper-case letters) to local variables (lower-case variables, say) and you're good-to-go. You may want to terminate the loop with `while (a-b).abs > tolerance`, where you have assigned `tolerance` a small value, such as `tolerance = radicand * 10*5`. As it is now the loop terminates when floating point precision is exhausted.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: @ThomasL.: The problem is that you did not use any variables in your code, with the sole exception of `radicand`, which indeed is a variable. The other ones are constants. The reason that you do get a result for your square root despite of this error, is, that Ruby has a somewhat unusual approach to constants: Constants **can** be changed (they are not very constant after all), but Ruby gives you a warning if you do so.

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't realize that capitalizing a and b would make them constants. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this where you use lower case variable names rather than [upper case constant names:](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html)

```
def square_root(radicand)
    a, b = radicand, 1
    tolerance = 0.00000000000000000001

    while (a - b).abs > tolerance
        a = (a + b) / 2
        b = radicand / a
    end

    a
    end

print "Enter the radicand:"
radicand = gets.to_f
puts "The square root of #{radicand} is #{square_root(radicand)}"
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter the radicand: 256
The square root of 256.0 is 16.0
```